# Running the wizard again after a new system installation

Tags: system-installation, linux-mint

I'm interested in installing Linux Mint on old laptops and giving them away.
During initial installation, I'm going to add VNC (or other tools to allow remote support), but interested in leaving the installation similar to that when you receive a new computer from a major vendor.

Example, if you buy a Dell machine and power it own, it asks you basic questions, Full Name, username, password, timezone, etc.

Is there a way I can setup Ubuntu (or Linux Mint preferred) to allow run a similar wizard on next reboot? See this as essential, since I'm not likely to ever meet the person that receives the machine I've just built. Figured it would be good to have that 'initial setup' wizard to make the person feel as if they are making the machine their own/custom.

Comment: There is already remote support on Ubuntu (using VNC), see "System->Preferences->Remote Desktop" you just have to activate it.

Comment: askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: Ah, didnt see that. Any suggestions on how to allow new users to setup the machine the first time they start it up?

Answer (score 1):

I barely know anything about Linux Mint anymore as they seem to have been diverting from Ubuntu for some time. But Ubuntu has an OEM install option. I think it's maybe only available on the DVD. You'll select "Install Ubuntu" and press F4 to display options. You'll find OEM Install, which will do what you want.

Comment: Googling for "mint oem installer" got me http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/747 which seems helpful.